# How to ensure android uses the default font?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I'm building an app and want to make sure it uses the default "sans" fonttype that android supplies.

I installed some strange font and set it as the font my phone uses so I can test if my actions are working.

Then I changed the theme that is used by all my screens so it includes the following line:

```
<item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
```

This does not have any effect though...

If I change the theme-typeface line to:

```
<item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
```

Then it does work, the odd font does not show, but I get the default android serif font...
The same happens when I use monospace...

But when I use sans (or normal) it uses the newly installed font.

Does anyone know a good way to accomplish this?

---

Edit: I need a way to set it for the whole app, not for every item separately

---

Edit2: Even if I set it in the xml it does not work.
By now I think serif has effect becouse the odd font does not have a serif version.
So android defaults to its own font then.

**How can I make andoid use its own build-in font always?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Becomes this:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

By defining an xml theme file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">shreif</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can also apply styles to all activities of an application:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Or just one activity:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: No, i've got over 10 activities, lots of views, two SurfaceViews where also text is written on.
This will not work.
I need a way to set it for the whole app.

Comment: I did that, does not work, it tries to use the sans / serif / monospace versions of the newly installed font, not the default droid font.

Answer (score 0):

This was a question I had some time ago and never found the answer for.
Thats OK. I think in the end: Every supplier of a device can give you another default font.

So I decided to package "my own" font in the app.

(Ah well, I guess everybody here is learning)